# Dicionário a partir de índice de lista

Tags: python

Tenho um lista de nomes = [nome1, nome2, nome3, etc]

Cada nome é para ter informações associadas, como endereço, telefone, etc.

Quero fazer um menu a partir do índice da lista:
print...

1 - Nome1

2 - Nome2

3 - Nome3

input("Digite a sua opção:")

## O dicionário a partir do índice da lista:

Se o usuário digitar 1, print os dados do nome1;
Se 2, dados no nome2;
etc...

Quero que, caso eu inclua ou exclua um nome da lista, o dicionário deve  vincular o novo índice ao nome, independentemente se a inclusão foi do início, meio ou fim da lista.

Ex.: lista [Pedro, João, José] ->

Menu:

1 - Pedro

2 - João

3 - José

Usuário digita '2' --> print dados do João

Se eu excluir João, dicionário vincula o índice 2 ao nome que ficou no  lugar de João:

Usuário digita '2' --> print dados de José

Tem como fazer um dicionário assim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer uma atualização automática de índices, como está escrevendo, não tem a menor necessidade de um dicionário.

Na lista a alteração dinâmica dos índices acontece naturalmente - se, se você vai acessar elementos em uma lista pelo seu índice, a performance dela é igual a de um dicionário. (Não que a performance faça diferença em conjuntos de dados desse tamanho em aplicações interativas - faria diferença para milhares de itens de dados e tempos de mili-segundos).

Em suma: use uma lista.
Como as listas funcionam com índice a partir de zero, você deve lembrar sim, de adicionar um "1" quando for exibir um índice na tela, e "subtrair 1", sempre que converter um índice digitado de volta para um índice da lista. Dependendo da sofisticação que você desejar, pode até criar uma classe que herda de lista, e faz essa diferença de índice automaticamente - e ainda pode aproveitar e converter o índice de string para int, de forma que não precisa converter internamente.

```py
class MinhaLista(list):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
         if isinstance(index, str):
              index = int(index.strip())
         if not isinstance(index, int):
              raise TypeError(f"ìndices do tipo f{index.__class__}  não são suportados")
         return super().__getitem__(index - 1)
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
         if isinstance(index, str):
              index = int(index.strip())
         if not isinstance(index, int):
              raise TypeError(f"ìndices do tipo f{index.__class__}  não são suportados)
         return super().__setitem__(index - 1, value)
```

O "if" a mais pra checar se o índice é inteiro é que esse código não vai suportar o uso de "fatias" - isso é, a notação com "lista[0:5]" para pegar uma parte dos dados em uma lista.

## convertendo a lista pra dicionário

Como mencionei, não é necessário, mas se quiser realmente transformar uma lista em um dicionário, isso pode ser feito em uma linha com um dict-comprehension - mas esse modelo não vai ter o ajuste automático de índices que você quer.

Para isso, dá pra usar a função `enumerate`, que num `for` retorna o índice de cada elemento da sequência, e ainda aceita um parâmetro opcional do número de ínicio da contagem:

```
dados = {indice: valor for indice, valor in enumerate(lista_de_dados, 1)}
```

## Dicionário de ajuste automático de índices

Se realmente fosse necessário criar um dicionário com ajuste automático de índices, isso seria possível - sim - mas como no primeiro exemplo, exige uma classe especializada.  Nessa classe seria necessário recriar todos os métodos que alteram o dicionário: `__setitem__, __delitem__, pop, clear, update, popitem, setdefault`, e, além de chamar o super() para realizar a operação, realizar a indexação do dicionário inteiro. A indexação seria uma operação custoza em termos de processamento - com a mesma complexidade algoritmica que remover um elemento de uma lista, mas em termos reais, muito mais demorada por que seria feito em código em Python em vez de rodar direto em código nativo.  Na verdade, o mais simples mesmo seria, em cada um desses métodos, descartar o dicionário todo, e recriar o mesmo de forma automática, a partir dos `values()` do dicionário anterior.

Dá pra criar um decorator pra ser usado nos métodos que precisam desse comportamento, e o código nem ficaria tão grande - mas não vou fazer, por que realmente no "mundo real" é melhor ficar com uma lista mesmo pra esse caso.